# InstallShield LE - relative paths for files in solution folder That are not part of content files

Tags: installshield-le

I am creating a setup from InstallShield LE. My setup contains files that are in solution folder but not part of content files. 
E.g. My solution Folder is *C:\MyProject\Project1\Dev*
And Files I want to add too InstallShield LE setup is at: *C:\MyProject\CommonFiles\Libraries*
So the path **C:\MyProject** is common and some developer can have this path as **D:\MyProject**. So I want to add relative path for *C:\MyProject\CommonFiles\Libraries* (Something like *....\CommonFiles\Libraries*). I tried editing .isl file of InstallShield LE but its not working. 
There is a table named "ISPathVariable" but I am not sure that about how to use it for relative path.
Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the issue resolved by manually changing the .isl file.
the steps followed are as below:

1. Add the files from the required location (say C:\MyProject\CommonFiles\Libraries) in InstallShield project
2. Close the Installshield Project
3. open the .isl file in Notapad
4. Add a path variable. To add the path variable, the path 
   variable "ISProjectFolder" gives the path to .isl file. In my cas the .islFile is at location *C:\MyProject\Project1\Dev\InstallShieldSetup* and CommonFiles location is *C:\MyProject\CommonFiles\Libraries* so to access common libraries, we need to go 2 level up from InstallShieldSetup folder.
5. So I added my new path variable **CommonPath** as 
   *CommonPath<ISProjectFolder>....\CommonFiles2*
6. And use this **CommonPath** variable in the tag  (where files added in InstallShield are mentioned) as  *<LumedxCommonPath>\Libraries\File1.dll* where the hardcoded path *C:\MyProject\CommonFiles\Libraries\File1.dll* is mentioned.
7. Save the .isl file and reload the InstallShield project.

Comment: is can be done via InstallShield's Installation designer:go to Path Variables and edit one you need to "<ISPROJECTDIR>\..\" - this example will go to parent folder